# How to access outside file from java jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar that is reading a file using below code:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
```

I want to run this jar using java -jar .jar command but I want to keep this file outside my jar, so that I can edit the jar file later on without touching the jar. Can anyone help me, how to run this jar so that it will pick up the file from outside.

Comment: Pass the file name as a command line argument and load it in the jar, maybe using `java.nio`...

Comment: (It's probably not the thread context class loader you want - it almost never is.)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches you can do that and it will depend on where would you like to place this external file. For the sake of this answer, I will refer to this file as *config file*

### Not In The Same Directory

The first approach is where you will need to place this file outside the JAR and not necessarily next to the JAR file in the same directory. In that case, you can pass the file location of the *config file* using either an environment variable (if you are running the JAR in a shell for example) or a Java property.

To use an environment variable, assuming you are using some Linux distro, then you can use the export command to set the value; something like this:

```
$ export CONFIG_FILE_LOC=/etc/myapp/config.file
```

You can then read the value in your code using the `System` class by using the following code:

```
String fileLocationEnv = System.getenv("CONFIG_FILE_LOC");
```

Alternatively, you can set this as a property by adding the following segment to your launch command:

```
$ java -Dconfig.file.location=/etc/myapp/config.file -jar myapp.jar
```

You can then read the value in your code using the `System` class for properties using the following code:

```
String fileLocationProp = System.getProperty("config.file.location");
```

### In The Same Directory

If you need the *config file* to co-exist in the same directory as your JAR file, then you can use the following code to get the JAR directory and then append the filename to it. Here's the code (assuming a class named `MyApp`)

```
try{
    new File(MyApp.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
 } catch(URISyntaxException exception){
    System.out.println("Exception");
 }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: For completeness, maybe also add that you can pass a filename as an argument on the command line to `main(String[] argv)`, and that relative paths may also work (if users take care to run your app with the proper current working directory).

Comment: Also "well-known locations" like `$HOME/.myapp/config`

Comment: I think you've got the `-jar` and `-D` the wrong way around.

Answer (score 0):

To open the file as a resoure, add the folder containing the file(s) you want to use, to your classpath:

```
java -classpath .;config -jar myjar.jar
```

This example adds the current directory and the config directory to your classpath.

Multiple folders can be specified by using a separator. On windows use ';' , on unix use ':' .

To open the file as a File, you can just use

```
new File("configfile")
```

which will look in the working directory (directory where you launched your java)